# Dynamically add attributes as object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm working on [bootstrap-multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect), I'm trying to add data attributes in the `dataprovider` method.

**Current**

```
var options = [
        {label: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1', value: '1', selected: true},
        {label: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2', value: '2'}];
```

In the code it maps these an `<option>` tag like so:

```
$tag = $('<option/>').attr({
                        value: option.value,
                        label: option.label || option.value,
                        title: option.title,
                        selected: !!option.selected,
                        disabled: !!option.disabled
                      });
```

**Desired**

```
var options =[
  {
    "label": "Item 1",
    "value": 1,
    "selected": false,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "some-attribute": 10001
      },
      {
        "another-attribute": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So it will render on the HTML element as `data-some-attribute="10001" data-another-attribute="false"`.

I started out adding this to the code (which I know won't work):

```
$tag = $('<option/>').attr({
                        value: option.value,
                        label: option.label || option.value,
                        title: option.title,
                        selected: !!option.selected,
                        disabled: !!option.disabled,
                        forEach(option.attributes, function(attribute){

                        })
                    });
```

The problem of course is you can't add a loop as an objects properties. 
Once this is working I can add a pull request to the repository. I did ask a question on the repo but decided to try and tackle it myself [Issue #592](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/592)
Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of adding another field `attributes`, why don't you just put them one after the other? (`label`, `value`, `selected`, `some-attribute`, `another-attribute`)

Comment: How would I identify them? If I'm to add this as a pull request it needs to be dynamic and allow the user to add as many attributes as they want. It would be easy to add one attribute, but multiple user-defined data attributes makes it a tad tricky.

Comment: The iteration has to happen after the element was created, as in `$.each( option.attribute, function(att) { $tag.attr( Object.keys(att)[0], att[0] ) });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing attributes from an array to an object, since attribute names should be unique. It also simplifies how you would get the data attributes on the element.

```
var attributes = {
  value: option.value,
  label: option.label || option.value,
  title: option.title,
  selected: !!option.selected,
  disabled: !!option.disabled
};

for (key in option.attributes) {
  attributes['data-' + key] = option.attributes[key];
}

$tag = $('<option/>').attr(attributes);
```

If you wanted to keep it as an array, you can do the following:

```
var attributes = {
  value: option.value,
  label: option.label || option.value,
  title: option.title,
  selected: !!option.selected,
  disabled: !!option.disabled
};

for (var i = 0; i < option.attributes.length; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(option.attributes[i])[0],
      val = option.attributes[i][key];

  attributes['data-' + key] = val;
}

$tag = $('<option/>').attr(attributes);
```

Doing this, however, provides no benefit and introduces complexity. If each object can have multiple keys, the code will need to change further.

Comment: Trying to test it, since Object.assign is ECMA6 and largely unsupported, is there another way to achieve the same results in a similar fashion? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Yes, just made modifications so you will not need `Object.assign`. Good catch.

Comment: Works great, regarding your suggestion about using an object instead of an array. Doesn't this limit the number of data attributes I can add?

Comment: It limits the data attributes to being unique, but you can have a nearly unlimited number of keys in the object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the element first then add the attributes to it.

So your code should be like this:

```js
var options = [{
  "label": "Item 1",
  "value": 1,
  "selected": false,
  "attributes": [{
    "some-attribute": 10001
  }, {
    "another-attribute": "false"
  }]
}]

console.log(options.length);
$.each(options, function(option) {
  var $tag = $('<option/>').attr({
    value: options[option].value,
    label: options[option].label || options[option].value,
    title: options[option].title,
    selected: options[option].selected,
    disabled: options[option].disabled
  });
  console.dir(option);

  $.each(options[option].attributes, function(att) {
    $tag.attr("data" + Object.keys(att)[0], att[0])
  });
  $("#mySelect").append($tag);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mySelect">

</select>
```